# Not seeing Create a Pull Request link in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, ide, azure-repos

In Visual Studio 2019, with GIT source control.

As I perform various source control tasks in Visual Studio, such as creating branches, pulling and pushing changes, committing changes, etc..., I see helpful popup messages in the IDE such as:
Repository updated to commit 1234...
Repository is already up to date....

Other developers on my team get similar messages. However some of them do NOT get this popup after they pushed changes to origin:

[image]

Those developers have to go to Azure dev-ops to create the pull request, which is an annoyance.

I am trying to figure out, with no luck so far, how to get this message to appear for them. Why all the other popups appear except for this is puzzling. Anyone have any suggestions? It is so handy to have that link to take you right to the pr page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue after I had to change my password because of the policy. I fixed it by simply logging out on visual studio & Git resource. When I logged in I created a new branch and pushed the changes, after this the pull request link came back.
Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

Try going to the Team Explorer window and reconnecting to your repo. That's what did it for me.

Comment: Thanks! (Old post, but it did help me now :-) )

But can anyone understand why Visual Studio makes things so difficult for us?
This should have been prompted for me automatically.